# Deploying ionic app as Website

Tags: cordova, web, angular, ionic-framework

I need some advice to deploy the ionic app to webapp.

1) Is it the ideal way to do it? Or I should build another set of webapp by using AngularJS2 ?

2) Those apps specific functions like content sharing, camera plugin and etc, how would it be alike when deploy at web?  Will ionic auto disable/remove it?

3) any specific setting require in order to run it at Web server? (Apache or IIS)

Any others thing I should consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) There is no problem in doing it. The idea is that you can take the contents of your `www` folder, put it on a web server, and woila, done. So, no, you don't need to write another app in A2.

2) So, if you write in your code (and you should) logic for graceful error handling for when the plugin is not available, something like:

```
if (window.somePlugin) {
    //do something with the plugin
}
else {
    console.log('somePlugin is not available');
}
```

in that case you don't have to change anything, again just do as suggested in 1).

3) IMO, none. I tested in Apache and in NGINX and both worked just fine.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Hi.. any concern on the security like the js that query the output from API URL? or regenerate the js to be not-readable?

Comment: If you are, you can obfuscate and minify your js. There are gulp tasks that can help you with that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify and https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-obfuscate